# An integral problem related to matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I am stuck in an integral problem:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\det\left(\mathbf{A}+k(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}_0)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}_0)^T\right)\right)^{-r_1}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\det\left(\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}_i)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}_i)^T\right)\right)^{-r_2}d\mathbf{x}$$

where $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are positive semidefinite matrices, $k$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive scalar constants, $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf{y}_i$, $i=0,\ldots,n$ are $d$-dimensional vectors.

Any help?

Comment: I would be very surprised if this had a simple closed form in general.  Do you have any reason to think it does?  Or are you just looking for whether it converges?

Comment: Well, I am not quite sure about it, but since it is a rational function, the closed form can be always obtained. I hope it can be simple... If not, then I will be also thankful if somebody can show me how to write a computer algorithm to calculate the integral.

Comment: In Maple, just use 
evalf(Int(..., x[1] = -infinity..infinity,..., x[d] = -infinity..infinity ))